# Prettier Code formatter not working on Vs Code on javscript language or any other even on format on save or any other form

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am trying to use Prettier on VS Code for Linux(Ubuntu) when formatting ReactJs Code which is Javascript but there is a problem or an error that keeps on occurring without any explanation or reason the output it shows is:
[image: Picture of the explanation given by Vs code I don't Understand]

```
**["INFO" - 9:25:54 am] Enabling prettier for range supported languages
[
  "graphql",
  "javascript",
  "javascriptreact",
  "json",
  "typescript",
  "typescriptreact"
]
["INFO" - 9:25:57 am] Loaded module 'prettier@1.19.1' from '/media/chetan/New Volume1/Pdhai/Projects/MUltiLevel Oauth/node_modules/prettier/index.js'
["INFO" - 9:25:58 am] Formatting /media/chetan/New Volume1/Pdhai/Projects/MUltiLevel Oauth/models/User.js
["INFO" - 9:25:58 am] Loaded module 'prettier@1.19.1' from '/media/chetan/New Volume1/Pdhai/Projects/MUltiLevel Oauth/node_modules/prettier/index.js'
["INFO" - 9:25:58 am] Using ignore file (if present) at /media/chetan/New Volume1/Pdhai/Projects/MUltiLevel Oauth/.prettierignore
["INFO" - 9:25:59 am] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "babel"
}
["INFO" - 9:26:04 am] Require config set to true and no config present. Skipping file.**
```

Comment: Also ctrl+shift+p was not working And I have changed the "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" which is  unsuccessful as well

Answer (score 1):

Go to extension settings and find *"Prettier: Require Confing"*. Uncheck the box. Should help;
[image: Unchecked "Prettier: Require Confing" option in extension settings.]